# Python Printing a given word in a box shape

Tags: python

Im currently suck on a question in which Im not sure how to resolve.
Im requried to print the following output using for loops
This is just an example as it should be able to display any string that is entered

```
+computer+
e        e
m        m
u        u
+computer+
```

I came up with the following code to attempt to print this example

```
#ask user to enter the base word
user_input = input("Enter base word: ")
base_word = user_input

#ask user to enter the side word
user_input = input("Enter side word: ")
side_word = user_input

i=0

print("+" + base_word + "+")
for i in range(0, len(side_word)):
 # get the ith character
 letter = side_word[i]
 # display the ith character

print("-{0}{1:>{,len(base_word)}} ".format(letter ,"-",len(base_word) == len(base_word)-len(letter)-1))
print("+" + base_word + "+")
```

However when I run this code I recieve the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
KeyError: ',len(base_word)'
```

line 17 being `print("-{0}{1:>{,len(base_word)}} ".format(letter ,"-",len(base_word) == len(base_word)-len(letter)-1))`

I did attempt to replace the `==`  operators with  `=` however i still get an error in the form of

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work for your desired output and no need to use formate.
More easire.

```
#ask user to enter the base word
user_input = input("Enter base word: ")
base_word = user_input

#ask user to enter the side word
user_input = input("Enter side word: ")
side_word = user_input

print("+" + base_word + "+")
for i in range(0, len(side_word)):
 print(side_word[i]+" "*len(base_word)+side_word[i])


print("+" + base_word + "+")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("-{0}{1:>{,len(base_word)}} ".format(letter ,"-",len(base_word) == len(base_word)-len(letter)-1))
```

`==` is comparison so it generally returns `True` or `False`, if you want to use keyword argument in `.format` use single `=`.
Note that name used must be legal variable name in order to work, `len(`...`)` which is function call is not, try to replace `len(base_word)` using for example `len_base_word`.

Comment: That was in my orignal answer but when I ran it I got this error                              
 "SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? "

Answer (score 0):

```py
#ask user to enter the base word
user_input = input("Enter base word: ")
base_word = user_input

#ask user to enter the side word
user_input = input("Enter side word: ")
side_word = user_input

print("+" + base_word + "+")

for c in side_word:
    print(c, end='')
    for _ in base_word:
        print(' ', end='')
    print(c)

print("+" + base_word + "+")
```